# How to scrape some text in html tags by using regex?

Tags: html, regex

I want do extract text from html tags or from web page by using regex strings?
Following are the task which i want to extract;

1

```
<div>Want to extract this text</div>
```

2

```
<span>want to extract this text</span>
```

3

```
<span>+91 11 3989 0000</span>
```

4 Need to extract address here(No 40 york street Hongkong)

```
<p class="location"><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i> No 40 york street Hongkong </p>
```

5 Need to extract Web Site(url) here(www.website.com)

```
<p class="location"><i class="fa fa-link"></i> <a href="http://www.website.com" target="_blank">www.website.com</a></p>
```

6  Need to extract email address here(emailaddress@yahoo.com)

```
<p class="location"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> emailaddress@yahoo.com</p>
```

How do this type of task with regex? Im using webharvy to scrape some data from web site.
Are there any converter to do this?
Hope your guidence.

Comment: There's a famous answer on StackOverflow which says [you should not use regex to parse HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).

It is much easier to use a purpose built program like [Beautiful Soup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/)

Comment: @TerenceEden beat me to it. I was about to post the same answer. You never mentioned which language you were working with, but in NodeJS there's an excellent package - [cheerio](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cheerio) - that provides a JQuery-like interface for web scraping in NodeJS.

Comment: A general one could be this: `/>([^<]+)<\//` [See it in action](https://regexr.com/3pnep)

Comment: @Sanxofon  it was extract the text with starting and ending tags. Like this way or not    >Want to extract this text</
>want to extract this text</
>+91 11 3989 0000</
> No 40 york street Hongkong </
>www.website.com</
> emailaddress@yahoo.com</
How to do it without tags part

Comment: @kaviducoolplus: What language do you use? (next time always add the language/tool tag to a regex question).

Comment: @ Casimir et Hippolyte  i use this regex with webharvy scraping software